# Add a whitespace to every second line and merge every second line in a text file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file of lets say this content

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want python to read the textfile and edit it to this, add whitespace to the start of every second line then merge with first line above, this is what it should look like

```
a b
c d
e f
```

How can I achieve this?

I written gotten this together but it only prints and doesn't save the contents to existing file, doesn't add white space

```
with open("text.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    str = ""
    for i in range(1,len(content)+1):
        str += content[i-1].strip()
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(str)
            str = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest differnt approch this also may works.

```
with open("text.txt") as file_in:
lines = []
for line in file_in:
    lines.append(line)

#lines ['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', 'd']

lines = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in lines]
for x in range(0,len(lines),2):
    print (lines[x], lines[x+1])
```

should give

```
a b
c d
e f
```

or else you can simply append spaces to list as follows and print accordingly.

```
for b in range (0,len(lines)-1):
    
    lines.insert(b*3,' ') 

lines.pop(0) # ['a', 'b', ' ', 'c', 'd', ' ']
lines= ''.join(lines)
for word in lines.split():
    print(word)
```

Gives

```
ab
cd
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first solution you gave me only adds a white space to the every second line but doesn't merge it into one above?

Comment: This is what it prints
```
a
 b

c
 d

e
 f
```

Comment: You need to print using loop see second set which is in loop. Both belongs to same solution

Comment: Are u sure?...I've tested second solution...first solution not tested..it should work...let me test

Comment: Yes, I used this code
with open("text.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line)

for x in range(0,len(lines),2):
    print (lines[x], lines[x+1])

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Ahh edited & Tested pls, Try it

Comment: Have u tested?.

Comment: Yes it works, I modified the code a bit I understand it now. Thanks for your help.